# Hiding elements based on URL

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to hide an element that is created dynamically, below is the code I have tried but for some reason the menu still appears after the JavaScript has run.  It works in an html page, but not in asp.net.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://www.test.com/xzy") != -1) {
       $("#Menu").hide();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Need the rest of your code please.

Comment: This is all of the code I've used.  It works in an html page but not in asp.net.

Comment: *"This is all of the code I've used."* And yet you mentioned some ASP.NET. You know, the part that was *different* from the HTML page where this works. Consider that *that* part might be kind of important.

Comment: In addition to @PaulRoub, #Menu is it only one element or many elements, # normally should be unqiue id. jQuery and asp.net, can gives some problems if Javascript not placed correctly in the code. this is what I have experienced earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the first step. Add a Document ready statement so javascript execute himself after DOM is loaded.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://www.test.com/xzy") != -1) {
         $("#Menu").hide();
    }
  });
```

if you need it to work in IE8, I read you can use this:

```
    r(function(){
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("http://www.test.com/xzy") != -1) {
           $("#Menu").hide();
        }
   });
   function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}
```

Credits to the [author](http://www.dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever).